# Два рисунка в одной ячейке

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, python-2.x

Есть изображение в ячейке

```
item = QTableWidgetItem()
item.setIcon(QIcon('img/update.gif'))
self.tableWidget.setItem(1,2, item)
```

Можно ли вставить еще одно рядом в одной ячейке и при нажатии на них инициировать разные события?

Comment: Можно. Попробуйте сделать виджет с двумя QLabel. Это виджет через setCellWidget установить в ячейку. Другой вариант -- через создания делегата, но это намного сложнее. Пример приложения с делегатами: https://github.com/gil9red/combustion . Я делал пример с setCellWidget, но только с одним виджетом (там тоже QLabel с гифкой был): https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/22225614a2d6e1931fe4d276d1c99dc6944b14f1/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/table__cell__gif__setCellWidget/main.py

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую...

Comment: Один установил так: label = QLabel(self)
pixmap = QPixmap('img.gif')
label.setPixmap(pixmap)
self.table.setCellWidget(2,2, label), а как два сделать?

Comment: `cell_widget = QWidget()` `layout = QHBoxLayout()` `layout.addWidget(label_1)` `layout.addWidget(label_2)` `cell_widget.setLayout(layout)` `table.setCellWidget(cell_widget)`

Comment: а вот работает, только рисунки почему-то немного обрезаны сверху и снизу?

Comment: а как теперь при нажатии на них инициировать разные события?

Comment: `а вот работает, только рисунки почему-то немного обрезаны сверху и снизу?`, а хрен его знает -- с setCellWidget особо не работал, наверное, обрезается под размер ячейки, т.е. нужно будет или размер виджета в ячейке менять или размер ячейки. `а как теперь при нажатии на них инициировать разные события?` -- обрабатывать вручную клики на label

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое!